# Scope of let in callback function, need understanding

Tags: javascript

I am trying a callback function

```js
function doAsyncTask(cb) {
  cb();

}

doAsyncTask(() => {
  console.log(message);
})

let message = 'Callback Message'
```

This gives error that message is undefined, which is quite understood.

But if I do

```js
function doAsyncTask(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb();
  })
}

doAsyncTask(() => {
  console.log(message);
})

let message = 'Callback Message'
```

This works when I make this code `async`.

I could not understand what this `async/setTimeout()` does so that the scope of `let` is changed and it is available to the callback function.

Please help me understanding this.

Comment: This is an event-loop concept...

Comment: This the most amazing expatiation of event loop by Philip Roberts. I think it will clear all your doubt.

[event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Answer (score 3):

## Explanation

What you've run into can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful).

`setTimeout`, in simple english, basically delays the execution of its callback function to the "next tick" of the execution.

Basically, the execution context is parsed and queued up. When the browser executes any `setTimeout`, the browser queues its callbacks to the end of the execution queue.

See the code below for extra understanding.

## Using `setTimeout`

```js
console.log('Queue', 1, '`timeout` function is defined.');
timeout = function(cb){
  console.log('Queue', 3, '`timeout` function is executed.');
  setTimeout(cb, 0);
}

console.log('Queue', 2, '`timeout` function is called');
timeout(function(){
  console.log('Queue', 5, '`timeout` callback is executed.');
  console.log(message)
});

console.log('Queue', 4, '`messeage` variable is defined.');
let message = 'Ok.';
```

If you see the sequence of the logging, you can see that the value of `message` variable is already available when the `cb` is executed.

## NOT using `setTimeout`

Now, compared the above code to this code below, you can see that without `setTimeout`, the `cb` execution is not "queued" behind but is called instantly. Making the initialisation execution of `message` variable execute *after* `cb` is called (which throws an error).

```js
console.log('Queue', 1, '`timeout` function is defined.');
timeout = function(cb){
  console.log('Queue', 3, '`timeout` function is executed.');
  cb();
}

console.log('Queue', 2, '`timeout` function is called');
timeout(function(){
  console.log('Queue', 5, '`timeout` callback is executed.');
  console.log(message)
});

console.log('Queue', 4, '`messeage` variable is defined.');
let message = 'Ok.';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is related to how the *event-loop* works, the `setTimeout()` execution is added to something called [`Event-table`](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-js-the-event-loop-959beae3ac40) and the js engine continues the execution.

> #### [`Event-table`](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-js-the-event-loop-959beae3ac40)
>
> This is a data structure which knows that a certain function should be triggered after a certain event. Once that event occurs (timeout, click, mouse move) it sends a notice.

The `event-table` doesn't execute functions, it's just to keep that function till an event occurs (timeout in this case), after the event occurs, that function will be placed into the `Event Queue`.

In your case, the `Event Queue` will have the following statement `let message = 'Callback Message'` before the event (timeout) occurs.

So, the stack (aka Call stack and LIFO btw) will contain an order of executions as follow:

1. `let message = 'Callback Message'`
2. `() => { cb();}`

The first statement will create a global variable/attribute into the Window object and then the callback will print the value of `message` which is an attribute in the Window object.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet `doAsyncTask` is called before the declaration of `message` as it comes before it.
In the second snippet you are using `setTimeout()` for calling `cb()`.  `cb` will called in the end of all the code.Hence the in second example `message` is declared before the `cb()`.

The **first snippet** is same as below

```
console.log(message);
let message = 'Callback Message'
```

The **second snippet** is same as below

```
let message = 'Callback Message'
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just because of execution order:

```
function doAsyncTask(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb())
}
doAsyncTask(() => console.log(message))

console.log("message is undefined")
let message = 'Callback Message'
console.log(`message has been initialized to ${message}`)
```

Outputs:

```
message is undefined
message has been initialized to Callback Message
Callback Message
```

Whereas in your first code, since you call `cb()` directly the line at which `message` is set hasn't been executed yet:

```
function doAsyncTask(cb) {
  cb();
}
doAsyncTask(() => console.log(message))

console.log("message is undefined")
let message = 'Callback Message'
console.log(`message has been initialized to ${message}`)
```

Outputs:

```
undefined
message is undefined
message has been initialized to Callback Message
```