# After an inline style has been added to an element, how can I tell when I can change it such that a transition will work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in the code below. If you change the style and then change it again right away, there is no transition. However, if you just wait a little bit, it will work. I'm wondering if there's anything that can be monitored to know when you can change the style again such that it won't bypass the transition.

```js
let one = document.getElementById('one');
let two = document.getElementById('two');
one.style.left = '100px';
one.style.left = 0;
two.style.left = '100px'
setTimeout(()=> two.style.left = 0, 100);
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  transition: left 1s;
}

#two {
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'></div>
```

Edit: This appears to be a simple case of using an no-delay `setTimeout`, and indeed that does work for my example code. However, in my actual code that does not work. I'm not sure what's going on. I am unable to make a simple example of it that doesn't work but I'm guessing it has something to do with having more content on the page.

Comment: whats your doubt Not understanding please explain clearly

Comment: No, there isn’t anything to “monitor”, this is due to how responsibilities are shared between the JS runtime and the rendering engine. As long as some “closed” JS functionality is running, the rendering engine sits dormant, and only gets handed control again, when the JS part is finished. The usual solutions to this are either setTimeout/requestAnimationFrame to force a “break” in the JS execution, or to read some value that needs querying the rendering engine to determine, such as the offsetHeight of an element.

Comment: @04FS For my actual issue, `setTimeout` does work if I make the delay big enough, but not if I make it have no delay. I had never heard of `requestAnimationFrame`. I just tried it however, and that also didn't work. But yes, perhaps I can monitor `getBoundingClientRect()` with `setInterval` to see when its `x` value changes. I will give that a try tomorrow if no better solution is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job both in my example code and my real code.

```js
let one = document.getElementById('one');
let two = document.getElementById('two');
one.style.left = '100px';
one.style.left = 0;
let left = two.getBoundingClientRect().left;
two.style.left = '100px'
let i = setInterval(()=>{
  if (two.getBoundingClientRect().left != left) {
    two.style.left = 0;
    clearInterval(i);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  transition: left 1s;
}

#two {
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching your problem the wrong way.

In fact, if you change your `setTimeout` duration to 0 seconds, your transition will work.

```js
let one = document.getElementById('one');
let two = document.getElementById('two');
one.style.left = '100px';
one.style.left = 0;
two.style.left = '100px'

// Change timeout duration to 0
setTimeout(()=> two.style.left = 0, 0);
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  transition: left 1s;
}

#two {
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'></div>
```

But why? If the duration is 0, Isn't it supposed to mean it will run immediately?

Yes, but no.

When you assign immediately:

```
two.style.left = '100px'
two.style.left = 0
```

Things get processed so fast that by the time the rendering engine gets the data, `two` is already at `left: 0`. So no transition will take place.

When you use `setTimeout`, it basically queues the task to the end of current queue. So it gives time for the rendering to register `left = '100px'`, then `left = 0`.

In essence, you cannot and don't have to monitor when you can change style. All you need to do is queue the job to the "next tick".

The above explanation is overly simplified. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) for more information. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113089/scope-of-let-in-callback-function-need-understanding/55113245) for some demonstration and also some detail explanation.

Comment: Doesn't really explain why it works and why it doesn't work without the setTimeout

Comment: @charlietfl was writing a more detailed answer. See updated.

Comment: Very interesting, I actually didn't even try doing `setTimeout` with no delay in this example, because (I thought) this was a simplified version of the issues I was having. Unfortunately this is not the answer however, because in the actual code I'm using, `setTimeout` with no delay doesn't work (occasionally it will, but most of the time it doesn't).

Comment: @Mason in that case, can you share a more detailed code? From your current code snippet, that's the only problem I'm seeing.

Comment: @YongQuan I really need to go to sleep right now. I will get on that tomorrow.